# What happens in C++ when we pass a recursive function as an argument to the function itself?

Tags: c++, recursion

In the below code, if I use just `factorial(n)`, it gives the correct output (120), but when I use `factorial(factorial(n))`, the result is 0. Could someone please explain what is going wrong?

```
int factorial(int);

int main()  
{  
    int n = 5; // number of terms

    cout<<endl<<"The factorial is:"<<factorial(factorial(n));
    return 0;
}

int factorial(int x)
{
    if(x==1)
       return 1;
    else
        return x * factorial(x-1);
}
```

Comment: Normally this would compute the factorial of 120.  However, it's likely that integer overflow is playing a role.  It's impossible to say without seeing how `factorial` is implemented.

Comment: Okay I am editing the details with full code for your reference.

Comment: You are not "passing a function". You are passing the value returned by `factorial(5)`.

Comment: Hence, I expect the value to be passed as 120, as 120 is returned by factorial of 5, but again factorial of 120 is not 0. That's where the question lies.

Comment: @Stuti Tip for the future: since you expected the value to be passed as 120, it would be reasonable to do a test where you try `factorial(120)` directly. Try to confirm or eliminate the second `factorial` invocation as a contributing factor.

Comment: In the same program, if I simply use return "x * fact(x-1)" in the recursive function, I get incorrect answer. But if I use " n = x * fact(x-1); return n;", that gives correct answer. Any explanation to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're hitting **[integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)**.

As you noted the factorial of 5 is 120.

So `factorial(factorial(5))` is the same as `factorial(120)`. As you can see you're not passing the `factorial` function as argument to the outer `factorial`. You're passing the **result** of the call to the inner factorial as argument to the outer factorial.
The code is equivalent to this :

```
int result = factorial(5); // result = 120
factorial(result); // factorial (120)
```

The problem is that the factorial of 120 is [a really **big** number](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=120%21), a number of almost 200 digits

Now this is way bigger than what an `int` can store. Or even a `long long unsigned int`. You need specialized libraries to handle arbitrarily big numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect explanation !

Answer (score 1):

`factorial(factorial(5));`

is effectively evaluated as if were written

`temp = factorial(5);  factorial(temp);`

Based in the fact that we know `temp` will be set to 120 (we were told the function works for argument 5), the question is what happens in `factorial(120)`.

The answer is: it overflows the maximum value of an integer.